# Microsoft Word: find all words with two 'm's using wildcard

Tags: microsoft-word, search, text-formatting, wildcards

How I can find every word in a Microsoft Word document
that contains two or more 'm' s, like "mermaid", "mommy", etc?

I have tried doing a wildcard Find using `<[! ]@m*>`,
and this finds all those words that contain at least one 'm',
but I couldn't figure how to find the words that contain two 'm's.

Comment: [Regular Expression Language - Quick Reference | Microsoft Docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/regular-expression-language-quick-reference)

Comment: @DavidPostill The wildcard syntax used by Word is very different from standard regular expression syntax.

Comment: Indeed. Posted wrong link. https://wordmvp.com/FAQs/General/UsingWildcards.htm should do instead.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to solve this and couldn’t develop a reasonable answer. 
But, since nobody else has provided *any* answer,
I’ll give you an unreasonable one:

Do six separate searches, for the following patterns:

- `<[Mm][! ]@m>`
- `<[Mm][! ]@m[! ]@>`
- `<[! ]@mm>`
- `<[! ]@mm[! ]@>`
- `<[! ]@m[! ]@m>`
- `<[! ]@m[! ]@m[! ]@>`

These correspond to the following patterns of words:

- **M** *something* **m**
- **M** *something* **m** *something*
- *something* **m** **m** <sup>1</sup>
- *something* **m** **m** *something*
- *something* **m** *something* **m**
- *something* **m** *something* **m** *something*

Strictly speaking, you should also search for `<[Mm]m>` and `<[Mm]m[! ]@>`,
but those match the word “mm” and words beginning with “mm”,
which don’t exist (unless you include initialisms).

Note that I began the first two patterns with `[Mm]`, to match words
even if they are capitalized (since wildcard searches are case-sensitive). 
If you might have words that are all-caps,
you should replace all occurrences of `m` in the patterns with `[Mm]`.

Also, I followed your example and used `[! ]` (anything other than space)
as a “word” character. 
This is really a bad choice;
it means that any string of consecutive characters other than space
qualifies as a word. 
Bad examples include “bumper-to-bumper”, “miles/minute” and “rum&molasses”. 
It would be safer to use `[A-Za-z]` as your word character
(which you follow with `@`).

P.S. I admit that this is not a terribly practical answer. 
One thing that might make it bearable is to write a VBA routine
that tries all six (or eight) patterns.
______________
<sup>1</sup> There don’t appear to be any actual English words
that end with “mm”,
but this pattern will match names like “Grimm” and “Hamm”,
and abbreviations like “comm” and “DIMM”
(if you use `[Mm]` to match upper- or lower-case “M”).