# How Can You Find Two Separate Words with Microsoft Word Wildcards?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office, microsoft-word-2010, wildcards

I've searched other answers for this - such as [Microsoft Word: find all words with two 'm's using wildcard](https://superuser.com/questions/1413293/microsoft-word-find-all-words-with-two-ms-using-wildcard) - but I can't find a solution to my issue.

## What I'm trying to do:

I'm trying to use the wildcard search function to find words that are

1. ending in **ing**
2. preceded by **to**

For example, *to going* or *to doing* would return a hit, but *are making* would not.

## What I've tried:

Looking at some documentation (e.g. https://wordmvp.com/FAQs/General/UsingWildcards.htm), I tried `to ing>`, `<to>[space]ing>`, and `(to)(ing>)` but none of that worked.

Surely, there must be a way for wildcard search to find more than one word?

Comment: Have you tried a Regex search?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can enter on the Find what box:`to <*ing>`. It will find *to going* and *to doing* but not *are making*. To match a word when using regex with MS Word you need to enclose it between `<>`. In your case, the find word ending with `ing`, you must use `<*ing>`. The `*` matches any number of characters.

Answer (score 1):

I find previous answer terrible because it would affect such string as *in**to Aerobic and Anaerobic Training***

Wildcard to find two words preceded by **to** and ending with **ing** looks as following:

```
<to> <[A-z]@ing>
```

where **to** is a separate word as in the example, not ending of a previous word such as **into**

- `<` is the beginning of the word
- `to` is the word
- `>` is the end of the word
- `[A-z]` any Latin1 alphabet letter
- `@` is that the letter
  occurs 1 or more times
- `ing` is the pattern in the second word

if want to include in VBA code, a possible string can be as following:

```
myPattern="<to> <([A-z]@)ing>"
```

1 For other alphabets read in https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/how-to-find-all-words-longer-than-a-specified/22753d47-05d3-4008-ab15-b68d2ef6a1ad

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).